# Vectorized way of adding to an array that is indexed by another array - Python/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have 3 Numpy arrays, `a`, `b` and `c`. 
`b` and `c` are very large arrays and have the same length. Each element of `b` is 0, 1 or 2 and also the length of `a` is 3.
Now I wonder if there is a way to eliminate the following for loop:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    a[b[i]] += c[i]
```

Any comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to eliminate the for loop and still have `a` modified that way?

Comment: yes, eliminating 'for' and have the same result

Comment: You have to iterate there is no other way, you can maybe merge 2 for loops so you only iterate once, but you cannot avoid it

Comment: Who talked about `a` ? I said if you have a for loop before that one you can try to put both treatment in the same loop. Show more code if you want help.

Comment: Give a small example so there's no ambiguity as what you expect.

Comment: There a was comment and asking about `a`. Anyway, simply the above `for` loop is inside another loop that iterates over time.

Comment: What are the shapes of `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: `a`, `b` and `c` are column vectors.

Comment: More likely they are 1d arrays.  `column vector` makes more sense in the MATLAB wordl

Comment: The key problem is that `b` has repeated indexes - e.g. `[0,2,1,2,1,1,0...]`.  That's the context that requires either the loop or `add.at`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for such `ID` based summing, like so -

```
a += np.bincount(b,c,minlength=a.size)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [136]: # Large arrays as inputs
     ...: a = np.random.rand(3)
     ...: c = np.random.rand(10000)
     ...: b = np.random.randint(0,3,10000)
     ...: 
     ...: # Make copies for testing
     ...: a1 = a.copy()
     ...: a2 = a.copy()
     ...: 

In [137]: def bincount_app(a, b, c): # bincount approach as func
     ...:     a += np.bincount(b,c,minlength=a.size)
     ...:     

In [138]: %timeit np.add.at(a1, b, c) # @user2357112's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

In [139]: %timeit bincount_app(a2, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

NumPy ufuncs have an [`at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method for cases like this:

```
numpy.add.at(a, b, c)
```

This does what everyone expects `a[b] += c` to do for an array `b` of indices before they see that it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps me very much.